# How can LiveDocx in PHP be used to read .doc & .docx files and read text inside it and save to HTML?

Tags: php, livedocx

Let's say we have a .doc & .docx files. I want to use LiveDocx in PHP to load the files, read it's content and strip the text from inside it. Then save it to an HTML string.

Can this be done?

I've searched the documentation, and it seams that LiveDocx only loads .doc & .docx template files only!

Comment: What about other plattform? I mean that you probably can find other platforms that have more feature than LiveDocx.

Answer (score 1):

You can save using external libraries and simply grab the text from the XML within the files:
http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/reading_the_clean_text_from_docx_odt.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find what you need in [this example](http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/08/13/convert-docx-doc-rtf-to-html-in-php/).

I might be wrong, but I think they call them "template" files because they *act* like a template but are still normal .doc/.docx documents. I suggest you simply try to run that example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use TextControl that improves phpLiveDocx [TextControl link](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/)

Using this you can also import pdf doc and docx

Answer (score 0):

When you do document conversion on LiveDocX, you need to do a mailmerge and then retrieve the document. Even though you aren't inserting any new content, you need to do a mailmerge that replaces a dummy placeholder with dummy content.

So, the process I'd suggest is:

1) Set your source document as local template
2) Merge a dummy field with dummy content
3) Retrieve your document as HTML
4) Use a script server side to remove the html and leave only the content (Something like, remove everything between the HEAD tags, then strip_tags on the rest)
5) You should be left with your content as a simple string - I'm not sure it'll be too meaningful, but might be useful for building something like search indices.